# Command to install GRUB2 on a BIOS boot partition

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, bios, gpt

For a BIOS system with a single GPT fixed volume and a freshly-created BIOS boot partition at /dev/sda1 carrying the bios_grub flag, is the correct command to install / embed GRUB2 (*i.e.*, core.img) to that partition:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
```

or

```
# grub-install /dev/sda1
```

[Section 4.4 of the GNU GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#BIOS-installation), on BIOS installation, is not express on this point, and [man grub-install](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/grub-install.8.html) has no information.  Unofficial sources also offer no direct guidance, some implying the former will auto-detect the partition and install / embed on it, others suggesting this may simply install on the boot sector and MBR gap (although whether this applies to GPT disks isn't clear), others discuss multi-boot configurations that are off-point, and yet others discuss installing on this partition without saying how.

A subsidiary question is, if the latter is required but the former has been run, how does one "uninstall" from the boot sector.  [Section 22.1 of the GNU GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell) states:

> At least on BIOS systems, if you tell grub-install to install GRUB to
> a partition but GRUB has already been installed in the master boot
> record, then the GRUB installation in the partition will be ignored.

First, does this statement apply to GPT disks, or GPT disks with BIOS boot partitions?  If so, must the volume be re-initialized or is it enough to run:

```
grub-install --recheck
```

Many thanks in advance.  No express guidance on this particular point exists or is obvious in this forum or elsewhere.

Comment: If grub never installed, you have to mount / (root) first, so grub knows where the rest of grub goes. It auto finds the bios_grub partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System If  you have separate /boot or other system partitions you probably have to mount those & then a full chroot works better. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot If UEFI you also mount the ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 Most systems now are UEFI (since 2012).